# Error with binding parameter in the query PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to GET my photo_id to load information about the photo from the database but i get an error with binding my parameter in the query.
I also want to echo my 'foto_titel' in a textbox but it don't show it.

Thank you very much for your help

```
<?php

    $fotonr = $_GET['fotoid'];

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM fotos WHERE foto_id = :fotonr');
    $stmt->bindParam(':fotonr', $fotonr, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute(array($fotos));

    $fotosArray = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($fotosArray as $row) {
        echo $row['foto_titel'];
    }

?>

<input id="naamfoto" name="naamfoto" value="WANT TO ECHO HERE" class="form-control input-md" type="text" required>
```

Comment: why don't you just try $stmt->execute([':fotonr'=>$fotonr]); ?

Comment: `$stmt->execute()` is all you need, you have done the binding

Answer (score 1):

I changed

```
$stmt->execute(array($fotos));
```

to

```
$stmt->execute();
```

And my full code:

```
<?php

$fotonr = $_GET['fotoid'];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM fotos WHERE foto_id = :fotonr');
$stmt->bindParam(':fotonr', $fotonr, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute(array($fotos));

$fotosArray = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($fotosArray as $row) {
    echo $row['foto_titel'];
}
```

?>